# Flask app working on dev server but facing issues when deployed on httpd with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, python-3.6, mod-wsgi

I got an assignment on one of the Python training that I attended. I built a simple app for one of my projects using flask 1.0/python3.6. My application need to achieve the following:

1. Call an API from an internal application at college.
2. Run a database query on Oracle db and display data on the webpage.

I wrote a bunch of functions in the backend (python) to achieve this and am using ajax to call these functions. Everything is running good in flask dev server. Now i need to move this to production server and I am using mod_wsgi along with httpd to achieve this. After some struggle I am get my application running on the production server, however my python code is failing with 500 error while running both functions.

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://server.com/flaskprod/requestbots 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

POST http://server.com/flaskprod/home 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

I checked the apache httpd error_log and I see the following errors.

Errors when calling API:

```
  [Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302510 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]   File "/var/www/flask-prod/flaskprod.py", line 230, in createCM
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302513 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]     r = requests.post(URL, auth=creds, data=json.dumps(DATAS), proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302515 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302517 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302519 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302522 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302524 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302526 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302528 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302530 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302532 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 502, in send
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302539 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212]     raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
[Mon Jul 02 13:48:41.302546 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18202] [remote 1.1.1.1:1212] requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='exampleee.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/now/change/change_req (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fac76d37eb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 13] Permission denied',)))
```

Errors when querying database:

```
    [Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148685 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148687 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148690 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148693 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148695 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148698 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148700 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148702 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]     raise value
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148705 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148707 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148709 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148711 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148714 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]   File "/var/www/flask-prod/flaskprod.py", line 97, in get_cms_requested_for_approval
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148716 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]     CMREQ = connect_bcc(queryCMREQ)
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148718 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]   File "/var/www/flask-prod/flaskprod.py", line 86, in connect_bcc
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148721 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]     connection = cx_Oracle.connect(bccConnectionString)
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148725 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212] cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
[Mon Jul 02 13:51:23.148750 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18200] [remote 1.1.1.1: 1212]
```

P.S Everything is running good in the flask dev server. No issues there. I am adding some more information below.

This is my config file:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On

WSGIScriptAlias /flaskprod /var/www/flask-prod/flaskprod.wsgi

WSGIDaemonProcess flaskprod user=cld group=users processes=5 threads=5 maximum-requests=1000 umask=0007
WSGIProcessGroup flaskprod
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<Directory /var/www/flask-prod/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Snippet of my python code:

```
def connect_bcc(query):
    connectionString = 'bla bla'
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(connectionString)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    return cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

 @app.route('/requestbots', methods=['GET','POST'])
 def get_cms_requested_for_approval():
    if request.method == "POST":
        queryCMREQFORAPPRVL = "SELECT * FROM....."
        CMREQ = connect_bcc(queryCMREQ)

        print (CM)
        return json.dumps({'CM': CM})
```

Snippet of js code:

```
function getResult() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/requestbots".....bla bla
         })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i figured it out. Yay for internet! I spent a while looking for answer to this question, so mentioning all details below.

Both issues were related to SELinux. If you're wondering what that is - Security-Enhanced Linux is a Linux kernel security module that provides a mechanism for supporting access control security policies.

In case, you run into a similar issue, check the SELinux boolean value for various booleans related to your web server:

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

For me, below two parameters were off.

```
httpd_can_network_connect --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
```

I turned them on using below command.

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on -P

setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db on -P

 (-P is used to make the change persisting)
```

That's it. Everything works like a charm now.