# Flask app running on Apache server/CentosOS 8 unable to connect to Mongo DB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, apache, flask, centos, centos8

### Background

I have developed a python flask app that uses the ArcGIS API for JavaScript to display geospatial data and query feature services from an ArcGIS Online account. Results from these queries are saved to a MongoDB Atlas cluster.

The flask app is deployed to an Apache server running Centos8 using mod_wsgi. It is currently working on a Heroku/gunicorn deployment.

Below is the code for the `app.py` code for the Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from data.database import global_init
from data.database import Query
from data.update import update
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = WhiteNoise(app.wsgi_app)
my_static_folders = (
    './static/css/',
    './static/images/',
    './static/js/',
    './static/layers/'
)
for static in my_static_folders:
    app.wsgi_app.add_files(static)


@app.route("/query", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def query():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        feature = request.json
        feature_name = feature['name']
        feature_region = feature['region']
        feature_query = Query.objects(name=feature_name, region=feature_region)
        if feature_query:
            response = feature_query[0].export()
        else:
            response = ''
        return response


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    global_init()
    files = ['./static/css/styles.css', './static/js/app.js']
    app.run(debug=True,
            extra_files=files)
```

Below is the wsgi.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import site

site.addsitedir('/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages')

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map')

from app import app as application
```

### Problem

The issue arise when the app tries connecting to the MongoDB Atlas cluster to query/retrieve data. When a polygon is clicked on the map, the connection to the cluster is refused and the following error is logged in the error.log:

```
[Thu Oct 21 20:19:46.800129 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430689:tid 139930235827968] [client 99.8.162.56:55543] , referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471649 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665] [2021-10-21 20:20:14,470] ERROR in app: Exception on /query [POST], referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471711 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471715 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471718 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     response = self.full_dispatch_request(), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471721 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471724 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471727 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471729 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471732 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471751 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     raise value, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471757 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471760 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     rv = self.dispatch_request(), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471762 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471765 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471768 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/app.py", line 51, in query, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471770 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     feature_query = Query.objects(name=feature_name, region=feature_region), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471773 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/manager.py", line 37, in __get__, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471776 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     queryset = queryset_class(owner, owner._get_collection()), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471778 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 214, in _get_collection, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471786 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     if cls._meta.get("auto_create_index", True) and db.client.is_primary:, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471788 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1031, in is_primary, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471791 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     return self._server_property('is_writable'), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471793 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 856, in _server_property, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471796 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     writable_server_selector), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471798 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 243, in select_server, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471800 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     address)), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471803 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 200, in select_servers, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471805 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     selector, server_timeout, address), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471808 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]   File "/var/www/dm.nhmarchive.org/lau-map/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 217, in _select_servers_loop, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471810 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665]     (self._error_message(selector), timeout, self.description)), referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
[Thu Oct 21 20:20:14.471814 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1430925:tid 139930051188480] [client 99.8.162.56:55665] pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6171cb5aa3baaebd849f82b2, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)>]>, referer: http://dm.nhmarchive.org/
```

The connection to the MongoDB Atlas cluser seems to be refused when `app.py` tries to perform a query. Below is the code used to establish a conncetion with the database instance in `database.py`:

```
import mongoengine
...
from mongoengine import connect
from dotenv import load_dotenv


# Connects to remote Atlas database
def global_init():
    load_dotenv()
    DB_URI = os.getenv('DB_URI')
    connect(alias='laumap', host=DB_URI)
```

#### Troubleshooting

1. **Adding the server's IP address to Atlas's 'IP Access List'**

   While I had `0.0.0.0/0` listed as IP Address (which should theoretically allow all addresses to my understanding), I added the IP address of the server to the list. This still did not work.
2. **Adding pymongo kwargs to MongoEngine connect()**

   A similar problem was posted on a flask app with Atlas depolyed on [python anywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/11805/). They suggested adding the following kwargs when connecting to a database:

   ```
   connect(alias='laumap', host=DB_URI, connect=False, maxPoolSize=1)
   ```

   This also did not seem to work.
3. **Adding HTTP Method Overrides**

   This was done as per the official [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/methodoverrides/):

   ```
     class HTTPMethodOverrideMiddleware(object):
      allowed_methods = frozenset([
          'GET',
    'HEAD',
          'POST',
          'DELETE',
          'PUT',
    'PATCH',
          'OPTIONS'
      ])
      bodyless_methods = frozenset(['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'DELETE'])

      def __init__(self, app):
          self.app = app

      def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
          method = environ.get('HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE', '').upper()
          if method in self.allowed_methods:
              environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = method
          if method in self.bodyless_methods:
              environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'] = '0'
          return self.app(environ, start_response)

     app = Flask(__name__)
     app.wsgi_app = HTTPMethodOverrideMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)
   ```

   I don't have any experience setting HTTP headers in a Flask, so I'm unsure if the above is configured correctly. But as it is currently, it did not change the logged errors.
4. **Testing the .env DB_URI variable in a python interactive session**

   Just as a sanity check, I made sure that the DB_URI was correctly formed in my .env file. Below is the code used in the python interactive shell on the server:

   ```
    >>> import mongoengine
    >>> from dotenv import load_dotenv
    >>> load_dotenv()
    True
    >>> import os
    >>> DB_URI = os.getenv('DB_URI')
    >>> mongoengine.connect(alias='laumap', host=DB_URI)
    MongoClient(host=['lau-shard-00-00.sybdh.mongodb.net:27017', 'lau-shard-00- 
    01.sybdh.mongodb.net:27017', 'lau-shard-00-02.sybdh.mongodb.net:27017'], 
    document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, retrywrites=True, w='majority', 
    authsource='admin', replicaset='atlas-xvjuv5-shard-0', ssl=True, 
    read_preference=Primary())
   ```
5. **Checking SE Linux Boolean values**

   As per [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141429/flask-app-working-on-dev-server-but-facing-issues-when-deployed-on-httpd-with-mo), I tried setting the following values to true:

   ```
   httpd_can_network_connect --> off
   httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
   ```

### Question

**Why is my flask app not able to properly connect to my MongoDB Atlas cluster** when it is able to locally, on my Heroku deployment and when I run `flask run` on the Apache/CentOS 8 server?

Is there some security settings in CentOS 8 that need to properly configured or is there something in the Flask app or wsgi script that may need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message (last line) you can see it is not attempting to connect to atlas, it's attempting to connect to `localhost` (the default if you don't specify a host). So the error will be with the connection string.

Looking at the code, are you 100% sure the `DB_URI` environment variable is set correctly? Maybe add some logging to confirm.